# Angular 4 typescript Cordova Camera plugin error "Property 'camera' does not exist on type 'Navigator'"

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova

I trying to build APK using Cordova. Web part code is written in Angular 4 typescript. While ng build it gives me following error

> ERROR in $/AngularCordova/my-app/src/app/app.component.ts (19,26):
>   Property 'camera' does not exist on type 'Navigator'. ERROR in
>   $/AngularCordova/my-app/src/app/app.component.ts (23,13): Supplied
>   parameters do not match any signature of call target.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare let cordova: any;
declare let navigator: any;
let device;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
    title = 'angular app';
    ngOnInit(){
      this.deviceinfo();
    }
    deviceinfo(){

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
        alert("On device ready event");
            try{
                alert('Using Cordova plugins with Angular 4. Cordova version: ');
            }catch(e){
                alert("Exception occures"+ e)
            }
        }, false)
    }
  openCamera() {
      if( window.navigator != undefined){
        window.navigator.camera.getPicture(
          (imageUri) => {
            alert(imageUri);
          }, 
          (error) =>{
            alert("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");

          }, {
              quality: 50,
              allowEdit: true,
              correctOrientation: true  //Corrects Android orientation quirks
          }
        );

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( navigator != undefined){
  navigator.camera.getPicture(
    (imageUri) => {
      alert(imageUri);
    },
    (error) =>{
      alert("Unable to obtain picture: "+error);

    }, {
      quality: 50,
      allowEdit: true,
      correctOrientation: true  
    }
  );

}
```

I replace the above code in openCamera function. Error occurs because i was trying to access the navigator object from window object.